# Rectangle class with three constructors

Tags: c++

I need to complete the Rectangle class.  Write 3 constructors and a destructor to satisfy the main() below.  Use constructor initializers for each constructor.
This is what is done:

```
   class Rectangle
    {
       float* length;
       float* width;
    ...
    ???
    ...
    };


    int main()
    {
       Rectangle r1;
       Rectangle r2(4.5,2.3);
       Rectangle r3(r2);
    }
```

This is how I filled up the rectangle class:

```
class rectangle
{
  private:
   float* length;
   float* width;
  public:
    rectangle();                    //default constructor
    rectangle(double w, double l);  //constructor with parameters
    rectangle(const rectangle&);    //copy constructor
    ~rectangle(void);
    double getWidth(void);
    double getLength(void);
    double perimeter(void) const;
    double area(void) const;
};

    ...........
    ...........
    ...........

int main()
{
   rectangle r1;
   rectangle r2(4.5,2.3);
   rectangle r3(r2);

   //statements

}
```

I just want to know if am doing it right or wrong. Can anyone see if am missing smth or need to add to rectanglr class?!

Comment: You just showed the declaration, which seems to be fine. But your implementation could be horrible wrong. Also, why would you save the dimensions pointer-wise instead of plain `float`s? (I guess this is some kind of contrived homework idea and not actually your fault)

Comment: @Zeta In fact, it’s a *certainty* that the implementation is horribly wrong. As you’ve noticed yourself, we can see this from the member variable declaration.

Comment: Why, oh why are you using pointers for a trivial class like `rectangle`, which has at most two values (a width and a height) and two more if you're also incurring spatial placement (x,y origin) ? If some academic said this is the way to do it, question why.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing wrong because the definition

```
Rectangle r2(4.5,2.3);
```

does not have a corresponding constructor. Also take into account that the class in the assignment is named as Rectangle not rectangle.:)

I think that instead of length and width (why did you declare them as pointers?!) you should define four data members that will denote four points of the rectangle.

Comment: `rectangle::rectangle(double w, double l)`, have a closer look to the second `main` ;).

Comment: Judging from the member functions, wouldn't having four points just complicate it for op. Also there are two classes Rectangle(probably provided) and rectangle (which seems to be op implemented).

Answer (score 0):

The declaration and the uses of the three constructors (default constructor, a custom constructor, and a copy constructor) look reasonable. Storing pointers to `float` does *not* look reasonable, however: you should just store `float`s (I would actually store `double`s unless I have a reason to assume that there are a huge mount of `rectangle`s). When storing `float`s, there is actually no need to have a copy constructor or a destructor. If you insist in storing `float*` and, thus, allocate memory, you shall also implement a copy assignment:

```
rectangle& rectangle::operator= (rectangle other) {
    other.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
void rectangle::swap(rectangle& other) {
    std::swap(this->length, other.length);
    std::swap(this->width,  other.width);
}
```